# USB Drive not detected or responding 13.04 | Power problem suspected

Tags: usb-drive

Hej,

a TOSHIBA USB 2.0 hard drive is not detected by lsusb or found via ls /dev/sd*.

According to [Paul](http://paulphilippov.com/articles/how-to-fix-device-not-accepting-address-error) the problem is related to the USB power, but after restarting the laptop without connected usb devices the output of syslog is the same (see below). Furthermore i am using a dual head USB cable to ensure power supply.

How can I get Ubuntu to enumerate/recognize my USB drive on my DELL LX502x?

ciao

```
Feb 18 12:32:32 laptop kernel: [  166.175281] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Feb 18 12:32:32 laptop kernel: [  166.175712] usb 3-2: Device not responding to set address.
Feb 18 12:32:33 laptop kernel: [  166.379229] usb 3-2: Device not responding to set address.
Feb 18 12:32:33 laptop kernel: [  166.582606] usb 3-2: device not accepting address 6, error -71
Feb 18 12:32:33 laptop kernel: [  166.694423] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
Feb 18 12:32:33 laptop kernel: [  166.694835] usb 3-2: Device not responding to set address.
Feb 18 12:32:33 laptop kernel: [  166.898418] usb 3-2: Device not responding to set address.
Feb 18 12:32:33 laptop kernel: [  167.101839] usb 3-2: device not accepting address 7, error -71
Feb 18 12:32:33 laptop kernel: [  167.213620] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
Feb 18 12:32:33 laptop kernel: [  167.214055] usb 3-2: Device not responding to set address.
Feb 18 12:32:34 laptop kernel: [  167.417702] usb 3-2: Device not responding to set address.
Feb 18 12:32:34 laptop kernel: [  167.621033] usb 3-2: device not accepting address 8, error -71
Feb 18 12:32:34 laptop kernel: [  167.732798] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
Feb 18 12:32:34 laptop kernel: [  167.733227] usb 3-2: Device not responding to set address.
Feb 18 12:32:34 laptop kernel: [  167.936909] usb 3-2: Device not responding to set address.
Feb 18 12:32:34 laptop kernel: [  168.140214] usb 3-2: device not accepting address 9, error -71
Feb 18 12:32:34 laptop kernel: [  168.140268] hub 3-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
```

Comment: Well can you please show me something? Connect the HDD then type `sudo fdisk -l` and post the output here. **be careful** it might take lots of time; up to 5 minutes! wait till it shows the line that looks like `user@host:~$`.

Comment: sudo fdisk -l only prompts partition informations for internall HDD. No additional informations is prompted by fdisk.